# OpenTK - VBO and Mesh, Memory Exception

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I have a class and I'm trying to render a single triangle with it but it keeps failing and i Don't know why, can anybody spot the problem? I've tried using static and dynamic vbo but i keep getting a memory issue.

The Error i receive is:

"
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in OpenTK.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
"

My usage is:

```
        var m = new Mesh();

        m.Vertices = new float[] { 
            0, 0, 0, 
            5, 0, 0, 
            5, 5, 0
        };


        m._Indices = new ushort[] { 0, 1, 2 };
        m.Init();
```

my class is

```
namespace lolGL
{
    using System;
    using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
    using OpenTK;

    public class Mesh : Entity
    {
        public ushort[] _Indices = null;

        int m_vertexBuffer = 0;
        int m_indexBuffer = 0;

        bool use16BitIndices
        {
            get { return Vertices.Length <= 65536; }
        }

        public Mesh() { }

        public void Init()
        {
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out m_vertexBuffer);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_vertexBuffer);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(BlittableValueType.StrideOf<float>(Vertices) * Vertices.Length), Vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.GenBuffers(1, out m_indexBuffer);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, m_indexBuffer);

            int indexSize = use16BitIndices ? sizeof(short) : sizeof(int);

            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(indexSize * _Indices.Length), _Indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);
        }

        public override void Render(OpenTK.FrameEventArgs e)
        {
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_vertexBuffer);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_indexBuffer);

            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
            GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Float, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);

            if (use16BitIndices)
                GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.TriangleStrip, _Indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort, 0);
            else
                GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.TriangleStrip, _Indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

            GL.Disable(EnableCap.VertexArray);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);

        }

        public override void EmptyBuffer()
        {
            Vertices = null;
            _Indices = null;
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            EmptyBuffer();
        }

        public override void Delete()
        {
            if (m_indexBuffer != 0)
                GL.DeleteBuffers(1, ref m_indexBuffer);

            if (m_vertexBuffer != 0)
                GL.DeleteBuffers(1, ref m_vertexBuffer);

            Dispose();
        }

        public override void ApplyColorMap(int[] colors)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Render function, you're binding the index buffer to the wrong target.

```
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, m_indexBuffer);
```

Should be:

```
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, m_indexBuffer);
```

Based on the way you're unbinding at the end, this was probably just a typo.

Also, unrelated but that whole thing you're doing with `use16BitIndices` is wrong. It's not the length of the array that matters, it's the size of each element in the array. If you have over `65536` **vertices**, you're going to need indices with a value greater than `65536` (which a `ushort` can't handle). You need to upload an `int[]` in that case.

Comment: On a different matter: Please don't [approve backticks for keywords instead of code edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2600211), see e.g. [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler My bad, I'll be more careful about those kinds of edits in the future.